# How do I set the "success" function for multiple ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I set ajax `success` for all requests done?

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(){ clicked = false;}
});

$('.button').click(function(){
   $.post('file.php',{},function(){});
   $.post('file.php',{},function(){});
   $.post('file.php',{},function(){});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean execute a single method once *all* requests have completed?

```
var counter = 0;
var nRequests = 3;

function multiSuccess() {
    // do something    
}

$('.button').click(function(){
   $.post('file.php',{},function(){
       counter++;
       if(counter == nRequests) {
           multiSuccess();
       }
   });
   $.post(...
   $.post(...
});
```

Also, you might want to look into [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/):

> Whenever an Ajax request completes,
>   jQuery checks whether there are any
>   other outstanding Ajax requests. If
>   none remain, jQuery triggers the
>   ajaxStop event. Any and all handlers
>   that have been registered with the
>   .ajaxStop() method are executed at
>   this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup) to specify default parameters for ajax calls:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  success: function(){ clicked = false; }
});
```